# Как пройти по списку но не проверять в списке итерируемый обьект?

Tags: python, python-3.x

А как пройти по списку но не проверять в списке итерируемый обьект?
Например есть список [2, 1, 3, 4]
нужно проверить если к значению добавить 1 (n+1) и он будет равен ЛЮБОМУ другому обьекту списка добавить его в новый список
на выходе должен получится список из [2,1,3]

```
def func_list(numbers: list):
    
    new_list = []
    for num_1 in numbers:
        for next_num in numbers:
            if num_1 + 1 == next_num:
                new_list.append(num_1)
```

Comment: у меня проблема что я сравниваю в списке и свое итерируемое число а нужно его както пропускать

Comment: print([x for x in numbers if x+1 in numbers])

Comment: спасибо большое! все так просто а я почему то начал мудрить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно его пропускать, так как это не влияет на решение. Число никогда не будет равно сумме самого себя и единицы, и поэтому не попадёт в результирующий список.